# How to use in clause in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like follows,

**Table1:**

```
ID      NAME    
------  --------
IM-1    Pencil  
IM-2    Pen     
IM-3    NoteBook
IM-4    Eraser
```

**TABLE-2:**

```
ID      ITEM_ID       
------  --------------
MT-1    IM-1          
MT-2    IM-1,IM-2,IM-3     
MT-3    IM-1,IM-2,IM-4
```

**Required Result is :**

```
ID      ITEMNAME
------  --------
MT-1    Pencil  
MT-2    Pencil,Pen,NoteBook  
MT-3    Pencil,Pen,Eraser
```

But by using the query

---

```
SELECT T2.ID, 
          (SELECT T1.NAME 
           FROM TABLE1 AS T1 
           WHERE T1.ID IN (T2.ITEM_ID)) AS ITEMNAME 
    FROM TABLE2 AS T2
```

I get the result:

---

```
ID      ITEMNAME
------  --------
MT-1    Pencil  
MT-2    (NULL)  
MT-3    (NULL)
```

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: It's not good to store comma separated values in database columns.

Comment: @knittl. The OP needs to do the reverse of `GROUP_CONCAT` on `ITEM_ID` before it can be joined to Table1.

Comment: [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) **Yes, it's really that bad.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT   b.ID, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(a.Name) as ItemName
FROM     Table2 b INNER JOIN Table1 a
              ON FIND_IN_SET(a.name, b.Item_ID)
GROUP BY b.ID
```

Comment: Thank u for ur reply johntotetwoo. got my required result.

Answer (score 1):

Without normalizing you can try this. But this query won't be SARGable, and as [ypercube pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082139/how-to-use-in-clause-in-subquery/9082369#comment11402970_9082139) storing a comma separated list in a db [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

```
  SELECT T2.ID,
         GROUP_CONCAT(T1.NAME SEPARATOR  ',')
   FROM TABLE2 AS T2
        INNER JOIN  TABLE2 AS T1
        ON FIND_IN_SET (T1.ID , T2.ITEM_ID )
   GROUP BY 
         T2.ID
```

Comment: Thank u for ur reply Conrad Frix. got my required result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.ID, T1.NAME as ITEMNAME 
FROM TABLE2 AS T2 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 AS T1 ON 
     FIND_IN_SET(T1.ID,T2.ITEM_ID)>0 AND FIND_IN_SET(T1.ID,T2.ITEM_ID) IS NOT null;
```

Comment: Thank u for reply ur MRM. got my required result.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is a recursive way to fetch the names of the items from a list of items.

it need to be done using a scripting language in a program..
sql doesn't support such way of fetching data..

you need to load the list of values in a string then split them then replace them with their values in the database..

Comment: Thanks Fahd Hamad Al-Abdulqad. But i can get my result by this query 
 SELECT T2.ID,
         GROUP_CONCAT(T1.NAME SEPARATOR  ',')
  FROM TABLE2 AS T2
        INNER JOIN  TABLE1 AS T1
        ON FIND_IN_SET (T1.ID , T2.ITEM_ID )
  GROUP BY 
         T2.ID